# If $g(x,y)=f(x) - f(\sqrt{y})$ is in $L^1([0,1]^2)$, then $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is in $L^1([0,1])$.

Tags: integration, analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am having more trouble with this than I thought I should. I am trying to bound the 1 norm of $f$ above by some value involving the 1 norm of $g$.

I have calculated
\begin{align*}
\|g\| &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 |f(x)-f(\sqrt{y})|dxdy \\
&\geq \bigg|\int_0^1 \int_0^1 |f(x)| - |f(\sqrt{y})| dxdy\bigg| \\
&= \bigg| \int_0^1 |f(x)|dx - \int_0^1 2y |f(y)|dy\bigg|\\
&= \bigg| \int_0^1 (1-2x)|f(x)|dx \bigg|
\end{align*}
Here the inequality is pesky and seems to lead no where. I've tried calculating with $g(\sqrt{x},y) = f(\sqrt{x})-f(\sqrt{y})$ as an upper bound and I also run into a pesky inequality similar to the one above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $g\in L^1([0,1]^2),$ then for a.e. $y\in [0,1],$ $x\to g(x,y)\in L^1[0,1].$ But the latter function of $x$ is just $f(x)$ minus a constant.

Comment: That was significantly easier than what I was trying.  Thanks.